# ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar not found error running Ant

Tags: xml, ant, jmeter

I already have a file called **ant-jmeter-1.1.1** in the path `C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras`.

But I am getting an error when I run the command **ant** from the same root:

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\build.xml:87: Reference C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar not found.

build.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<project name="ant-jmeter" default="all">
<description>

    Sample build file for use with ant-jmeter.jar
    See http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php

To run a test and create the output report:
    ant -Dtest=script

To run a test only:
    ant -Dtest=script run

To run report on existing test output
    ant -Dtest=script report

The "script" parameter is the name of the script without the .jmx suffix.

Additional options:
    -Dshow-data=y - include response data in Failure Details
    -Dtestpath=xyz - path to test file(s) (default user.dir).
                     N.B. Ant interprets relative paths against the build file
    -Djmeter.home=.. - path to JMeter home directory (defaults to parent of this build file)
    -Dreport.title="My Report" - title for html report (default is 'Load Test Results')

    Deprecated:
    -Dformat=2.0 - use version 2.0 JTL files rather than 2.1

</description>

<property name="testpath" value="${user.dir}"/>
<property name="jmeter.home" value="${basedir}/.."/>
<property name="report.title" value="Load Test Results"/>

<!-- Name of test (without .jmx) -->
<property name="test" value="Test"/>

<!-- Should report include response data for failures? -->
<property name="show-data" value="n"/>

<property name="format" value="2.1"/>

<condition property="style_version" value="">
    <equals arg1="${format}" arg2="2.0"/>
</condition>

<condition property="style_version" value="_21">
    <equals arg1="${format}" arg2="2.1"/>
</condition>

<condition property="funcMode">
    <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
</condition>

<condition property="funcMode" value="false">
  <not>
    <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
  </not>
</condition>

<!-- Allow jar to be picked up locally -->
<path id="jmeter.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
      <include name="ant-jmeter*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef
    name="jmeter"
    classpathref="C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar"
    classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"/>

<target name="all" depends="run,report"/>

<target name="run">
    <echo>funcMode = ${funcMode}</echo>
    <delete file="${testpath}/${test}.html"/>
    <jmeter
        jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
        testplan ="C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\SP-TRY.jmx"
        resultlog="C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\SP-TRY.jtl">
    <!--
        <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx128m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
        <jmeterarg value="-qextra.properties"/>
    -->
        <!-- Force suitable defaults -->
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
        <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
    </jmeter>
</target>

<property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter.home}/lib"/>

<!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ -->
<path id="xslt.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="report" depends="xslt-report,copy-images">
    <echo>Report generated at ${report.datestamp}</echo>
</target>

<target name="xslt-report" depends="_message_xalan">
    <tstamp><format property="report.datestamp" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"/></tstamp>
    <xslt
        classpathref="xslt.classpath"
        force="true"
        in="C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\SP-TRY.jtl"
        out="C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\SP-TRY.html"
        style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report${style_version}.xsl">
        <param name="showData" expression="${show-data}"/>
        <param name="titleReport" expression="${report.title}"/>
        <param name="dateReport" expression="${report.datestamp}"/>
    </xslt>
</target>

<!-- Copy report images if needed -->
<target name="copy-images" depends="verify-images" unless="samepath">
    <copy file="${basedir}/expand.png" tofile="${testpath}/expand.png"/>
    <copy file="${basedir}/collapse.png" tofile="${testpath}/collapse.png"/>
</target>

<target name="verify-images">
    <condition property="samepath">
            <equals arg1="${testpath}" arg2="${basedir}" />
    </condition>
</target>

<!-- Check that the xalan libraries are present -->
<condition property="xalan.present">
      <and>
          <!-- No need to check all jars; just check a few -->
        <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
        <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler"/>
      </and>
</condition>

<target name="_message_xalan" unless="xalan.present">
      <echo>Cannot find all xalan and/or serialiser jars</echo>
    <echo>The XSLT formatting may not work correctly.</echo>
    <echo>Check you have xalan and serializer jars in ${lib.dir}</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You say you have the file `ant-jmeter-1.1.1` in the path `C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras`. However, the file name should be `ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar` with `.jar` at the end.

Comment: Would you like to try using path separator change to '/' from '\'?

Comment: @rao - Getting same error yet.

Comment: @HelpingHands, Did you try in debug mode, you might get a clue?

Comment: @Rao - How can I use debug mode for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar file should be placed under ANT_HOME/lib folder. Not under JMETER_HOME.

If you are trying to use Ant for JMeter tests, I would advise you to check this.
http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/